# On GCE, sudden disk I/O and can no longer SSH in

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've been running a long job on GCE with a GPU.  It is not a preemptible instance.

I was monitoring the job on a local terminal with SSH and TMUX on the instance so it keeps running if the SSH connection gets broken.  The screen froze so I tried to SSH from another terminal window, but SSH also froze.

I went to the Google cloud console to try to see what is going on, and there are a lot of disk reads going on:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that nothing I've done has caused the disk reads.

Any idea what is going on?  I hope my job is still running and I don't want to start over again so I'd rather not stop and restart my instance.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your VM instance using gloud: gcloud compute ssh --project [PROJECT_ID] --zone [ZONE] [INSTANCE_NAME] More info about this [command.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) If the SSH communication is unavailable, you can try accessing the VM instance through [Serial Console.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) Also you can review the [Serial Console Output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output) for more details an

Comment: I'll bet it's swapping itself into catatonia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Womble is right that it is a memory and swap issue.

When the instance was working, I SSH'ed in and ran a small quick job, and I think that pushed the memory requirements over the edge.  This condition lasted for hours so I stopped and restarted the instance.

When I started the job over from scratch the problem happened again.  The job worked previously, so I'm going to wipe this instance out completely and create a new one from scratch and hope that it works again.

I can't increase memory because I'm already using the max.